# Any software for ubuntu 14.04 for doing mathematics algebric and functional graph problem with Calculus support

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation

Searching for an all in one software for mathematics.

Comment: Take a look at SageMath http://www.sagemath.org/ , or for primarily numerical calculations, GNU Octave is well suited.

Answer (score 0):

I use **[R](https://www.r-project.org/)** for simple Calculus, such as defining functions, plotting functions, differentiation, etc. For instance, defining a quadratic function:

`f = function(x){x^2}`

And then plotting it in the [1, 10] domain:

```
plot(f, 0, 10)
```

Defining a derivative function:

```
D = function(f,delta=.000001){
    function(x){ (f(x+delta) - f(x-delta))/(2*delta)} }
```

And then plotting the derivative of *f*:

```
plot(D(f), 0, 10)
```

For an overview of Calculus with R you can read [this presentation](https://www.r-project.org/conferences/useR-2007/program/presentations/kaplan.pdf).

I also recommend you use a GUI, to facilitate the interaction with R and help organising your projects. I use [StatET](http://www.walware.de/goto/statet), an Eclipse plug-in; [RStudio](http://rstudio.com/) is also quite popular.

To install R you can follow the [Ubuntu specific instructions at CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/#installation).

Comment: Thanks, Your answer helped me alot :) can you tell me how can i install R using terminal ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you already use ubuntu, why not using **python**? ubuntu ships with python by default. There are lots of available resources for running mathematics with python.